# Ionic CLI 6.20.1 unable to generate Service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, service, generate

Getting following error when I run

**ionic generate service api/user**

**[ERROR] type must be one of: component, directive, page, pipe, provider, tabs **(not service)****

Using Ionic CLI 6.20.1 ( documentation state generate service is supported )

```
Angular CLI: 14.1.3
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: npm 8.17.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1401.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         14.1.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   14.1.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          14.1.3 (cli-only)
rxjs                         5.5.11
typescript                   2.6.2
```

Comment: Try `ionic g provider api/user`

Comment: I tried that it works. Just wondering why it does not match the documentation for Ionic CLI 6.20.1

Answer (score 0):

I was referencing old doc so was running Ionic start command incorrectly

```
Wrong command -> `ionic start name tabs --type=ionic-angular -capacitor`
Right command -> ionic start name tabs --type=angular --capacitor
```

Running it incorrectly also resulted in Environment.ts not being created.

Comment: "--type=ionic-angular" isn't exactly wrong, it just creates an Ionic 2/3 project.
Type "ionic start --help" to see a list of options and examples, and you will see, in the list of examples, "ionic start myApp super --type=ionic-angular". The example for a more modern angular project is not given.
Type "ionic start --list" for a list of options, and you will see that "--type=ionic-angular" is for a Ionic 2/3 project, while "--type=angular" is for a newer Angular project.